# DataTable formatting datetime column in table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datetime, datatable

I am using the DataTable plugin to display a mySQL database table in a dynamic way. The table uses the datetime format for the column "checkinDateTime". In my table, it formats the date/time as `2016-04-15 14:27:36`. I would like to make this more readable, possibly formatted like `April 15, 2016, 2:27 pm`

Here is my code:

Reports.php (this is where the user can view the table. I'm only going to show the DataTables script and its settings):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#checkin').DataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "serverSide": false,
        "dom": 'lBfrtip',
     "buttons": [
        {
            extend: 'collection',
            text: 'Export',
            buttons: [
                'copy',
                'excel',
                'csv',
                'pdf',
                'print'
            ]
        }
    ],
        "ajax":{
            url :"response.php", // json datasource
            type: "post",  // type of method  ,GET/POST/DELETE
            data: {}
            }
        });   
});
</script>
```

Response.php (how DataTables pulls in the data):

```
<?php
//include connection file 
include_once("../connection.php");

// initilize all variable
$params = $columns = $totalRecords = $data = array();

$params = $_REQUEST;

//define index of column
$columns = array( 
0 => 'id',
1 => 'suid', 
2 => 'staffMember',
3 => 'studentName',
4 => 'studentEmail',
5 => 'checkinDateTime'
);

$where = $sqlTot = $sqlRec = "";

// check search value exist
if( !empty($params['search']['value']) ) {   
$where .=" WHERE ";
$where .=" ( studentName LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";    
$where .=" OR staffMember LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";
$where .=" OR studentEmail LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";
$where .=" OR suid LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";
$where .=" OR checkinDate LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' )";
}

// getting total number records without any search
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `checkin` ";
$sqlTot .= $sql;
$sqlRec .= $sql;
//concatenate search sql if value exist
if(isset($where) && $where != '') {

$sqlTot .= $where;
$sqlRec .= $where;
}


//$sqlRec .=  " ORDER BY ". $columns[$params['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$params['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$params['start']." ,".$params['length']." ";

$queryTot = mysqli_query($VisitorManagement, $sqlTot) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($VisitorManagement));


$totalRecords = mysqli_num_rows($queryTot);

$queryRecords = mysqli_query($VisitorManagement, $sqlRec) or die("error to fetch check-in data");

//iterate on results row and create new index array of data
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_row($queryRecords) ) { 
$data[] = $row;
}   

$json_data = array(
    "draw"            => intval( $params['draw'] ),   
    "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalRecords ),  
    "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalRecords),
    "data"            => $data   // total data array
    );

echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format
?>
```

Connection.php (access to the database):

```
<?php
$hostname_VisitorManagement = "localhost";
$database_VisitorManagement = "visitor-management";
$username_VisitorManagement = "****";
$password_VisitorManagement = "****";
$VisitorManagement = mysqli_connect($hostname_VisitorManagement, $username_VisitorManagement, $password_VisitorManagement, $database_VisitorManagement);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
?>
```

I have looked through their support forums and on here as well, but I didn't find a solution that could work with my code.

Comment: To me it is not clear, what the problme is. Maybe it would help to show your trial that came closest. I remember doing date localization via java script, via php, via SQL, there are quite some layers, where one might want to do it. But eventually someone else knowing "datatable" or the like knows the one best solution already ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to do this via MySql, instead of

```
SELECT * FROM `checkin`
```

use

```
Select field1,field2,..., date_format(checkinDateTime,'%d %b, %Y, %h:%i %p') as checkinDateTime
```

If it doesn't work, do it via [datatables's date plugin](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18)